# Introducing new poles

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose we have a contour integral of an entire function along a line in the plane (or perhaps a line segment).  I am looking for examples of such integrals that are computed by first altering the integrand so that poles are *introduced*.

An example that I have found is the proof of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$ from Remmert's book on complex analysis. A discussion of that can be found here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis/34772#34772

Can anyone direct me to other examples that might be similar to this?

Comment: A simple Google gives you, for example, this: [link](http://www.thomasbeatty.com/MATH%20PAGES/ARCHIVES%20-%20NOTES/Complex%20Variables/Contour%20Integral%20Examples.pdf) But any decent book in Complex Analysis, like Stein, Gamelin, Conway should have plenty of examples.

Comment: I agree that a "simple" Google search gives plenty of examples of residue integrals, but I am looking for something a bit more specific: an integral of an _entire_ function solved by _introducing_ one or more poles, as in the example I mentioned.